# Strange replication failure on date field under MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7, amazon-rds, date

This problem cropped up yesterday and I'm quite stumped. I have a primary RDS cluster that is running MySQL 5.6 and RDS is forcing everyone to 5.7 soon. I have a smaller standalone replication slave we use for some heavy reporting queries. The slave was moved to 5.7 yesterday (I think RDS didn't allow the primary to upgrade while the slave was upgrading), and replication ran fine for about 6 hours, but finally stopped hard with this 1292 SQL error

```
Error 'Incorrect date value: '' for column 'delivery_date' at row 1' on query. 
Default database: 'dbname'. Query: 'INSERT shipment SET
                    carrier = "Shipper",
                    bill_number = "1234",
                    tracking_num = "1234",
                    invoice_date = "2021-07-08",
                    fee = "1.00",
                    ship_date = "2021-06-10",
                    delivery_date = NULL,
                    zip_from = "ABCD",
                    zip_to = "",
                    recipient = "||",
                    shipper = "COMPANY",
                    notes = "||||",
                    found = "No"'
```

This error doesn't make sense. That field allows NULL so it shouldn't be an issue. Here's the structure

```
CREATE TABLE `shipment` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `carrier` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `bill_number` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `tracking_num` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_date` date NOT NULL,
  `fee` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `ship_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `recipient` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipper` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip_from` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip_to` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text,
  `found` enum('No','Yes','PO','Invoice','Event','Manual','Fee','Supplies') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `carrier` (`carrier`,`bill_number`,`tracking_num`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the `sql-mode` from the config

```
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

I've tried removing `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and even most of the whole set of configs there (RDS won't let you blank the field) and no luck. Our development server has used 5.7 for quite some time and accepts the query without complaint (both are 5.7.34). Skipping doesn't help because there are several dozen records it needs to update like this so it still breaks.

Apparently there was a trigger not in the live DB that is still on the replication server

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@% TRIGGER invoice_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON shipment 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NEW.delivery_date = "" THEN SET NEW.delivery_date = NULL; 
END IF; 
END
```

Comment: The move from 5.6 to 5.7 finished succesfully?  No traces left of the 5.7 binaries on the slave?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I assume so. This is an RDS instance, so I don't have control over the binaries it's using. The DB is running fine in every other respect

Comment: hm this should run https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=0161b2d0566a24b0c6a7161e40adaaae

Comment: Strange that the error doesn't correspond to the insert statement.  There wouldn't be an insert trigger on that table?

Comment: I take it back. I was looking at the live server, which has no triggers. This one had one that was removed. CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `invoice_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `shipment` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF NEW.delivery_date = "" THEN
  SET NEW.delivery_date = NULL;
 END IF;
END

Comment: "I think RDS didn't allow the primary to upgrade while the slave was upgrading" -- Good for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the trigger, change

```
IF NEW.delivery_date = ""
```

to

```
IF NEW.delivery_date < '1971-01-01'
```

That will catch empty string and `'1970-01-01' and any timezone variation on that "zero" date.  It will fail if it is already` NULL`, but that won't change the action of the Trigger.

(In the future, be sure to include any relevant Triggers in the Question.)